# Unable to connect Unity to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying out Unity for my Game Design course, but I can't seem to get the code to work. I suspect it is because Visual Studio (which I write my code on) is not connecting to Unity properly, and here's why I think this:

For one thing, whenever I try to put the code on an object, it prints out this error:

> Can't add script behaviour CallbackExecutor. The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!

This is despite the fact that nowhere is the code called `CallbackExecutor`, and the script apparently does derive from `MonoBehaviour`.

Second, when I load up the code onto Visual Studio, I get this error message:

> C:\Users\cemya\Documents\D&D Roguelight Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj : error : The project file could not be loaded. Could not find file 'C:\Users\cemya\Documents\D&D Roguelight Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'. C:\Users\cemya\Documents\D&D Roguelight Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj

The problem is I don't know why it's not connecting. There's no option to import the package (which implies it's already imported), and I do have a package for Unity.

I'm using Visual Studios 2017 (specifically, I'm using the 2d setup most of the time), Unity version 2018.2.4f1, and the package is called Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Unity [Experimental], which is what was automatically downloaded when I began to set up coding for Unity. Since I got this version automatically, I believe that this should be a common problem, but I can't seem to find real answers on it (I even asked on the Unity forms themselves!)

I can show you the code if you think that would help.

UPDATE: I have just updated Unity to 2018.2.5f1 and tested it with the code that has actual code. All that happened is that the name for the error message is different:

> Can't add script behaviour TMP_CoroutineTween. The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!

Also, here is the code for the one I'm testing, if it helps:

```
public class RollScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int r = 20;
    int m = 5;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        int rolling = DieRoll(r, m);
        print(rolling);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {       
    }

    int DieRoll (int roll, int mod)
    {
        int get = rand.next(1, roll);
        int result = get + mod;
        return result;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: I have checked with visual studio, and the error message there isn't there anymore, so that's an improvement.

UPDATE 3: I have created a new project and I have not run into issues there. I guess the problem was the code's connection to older editions.

Comment: The first error really has nothing to do with Visual Studio. This is the 4th time this question has been asked this month and I now think there is a bug in new Unity.  Did you download the code or create it yourself?

Comment: I created it myself. I can post the code if you want. Also I have had this problem with previous versions from earlier this year.

Comment: Yes, you should. Edit your question and post everything inside it. Also, post a screenshot of where it is located in your project.

Comment: I realized that the code I was using wasn't really filled so I went to double check with the code that actually had stuff in it, but then Unity suddenly have a new update out of nowhere. I'll test the code after it updates, then if it still has a problem, I'll put it in.

Comment: You format code by prefixing it with four spaces.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Thank you for your help with formatting.

Comment: Does that file C:\Users\cemya\Documents\D&D Roguelight Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj exist where Unity says it's looking for it?

Comment: I don't really know. How do I check?

Answer (score 0):

This `Can't add script behaviour TMP_CoroutineTween. The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!` error has been mentioned in a [few](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/9lwhxk/copied_this_from_lynda_for_the_2d_tutorial_but_it/) [places](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-add-script-behaviour-tmp_coroutinetween-the-script-needs-to-derive-from-monobehaviour.550174/) [on](https://community.gamedev.tv/t/the-script-needs-to-derive-from-monobehaviour/80073) the [internet](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-add-script-behaviour-tmp_coroutinetween-the-script-needs-to-derive-from-monobehaviour.550183/), but with no satisfactory answers. This seems to be the only StackOverflow question about it.

I *suspect* it happens when there are un-fixed compile-time errors while you're adding a script to a GameObject. I had this problem just now, and after I fixed the errors, I was able to add the script. However, I tried to confirm this by adding a syntax error and then adding a script, but I still didn't get the `Can't add script behavior` error. So that's odd, but if you're encountering that error, I suggest fixing any compile-time errors and see if that works. (Whether it works or not, please reply to this question with the result.)